# Django, filtering the most recently added element

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to retrieve the most recently added element and if there is none at all, assign some default values such as:

```
query = X.objects.filter(name="aa",type="b")[0]
if query:
    resultname =query.name
    resulttype = query.type
else:
    resultname = "a default name"
    resulttype = "a default type"
```

This is not working as it will raise an exception when the first line,  `query = X.objects.filter(name="aa",type="b")[0]`, executes and the filtered query list is empty.

Comment: This does not necessarily fetch the most recently added element. Just the first element of the `QuerySet`. You have to order by a field of the model e.g. `created_at`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing a `QuerySet` results in a single model, if any exist. Either catch the exception if none exist, or use `len()` beforehand on the `QuerySet` to see if any records were found.

Comment: what would be the related exception if none exists? Thanks

Comment: except IndexError: seems to fix it, ty